# Calculate the limit: $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{a}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits, functions, convergence-divergence

> Calculate the limit: $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\ln x}{x^{a}}$$

When try calculate limit, we get $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, so use L'Hôpital again.

$$(\ln x)' = \frac{1}{x}$$

$$x^{a} = e^{\ln x \cdot a} \Rightarrow (e^{\ln x \cdot a})'= e^{\ln x \cdot a} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \cdot a$$

$$\Rightarrow$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\frac{1}{x}}{e^{\ln x \cdot a} \cdot \frac{1}{x} \cdot a}= \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{x}{e^{\ln x \cdot a} \cdot a \cdot x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{e^{\ln x \cdot a} \cdot a} = \frac{1}{\infty} = 0$$

Is correct result and limit?

Comment: This is correct if $a > 0$ and incorrect if $a < 0$.

Comment: Oh thank you I forget write this important info!

Comment: @tenepolis $1\over\infty$ is not defined.

Comment: But divide with something big is zero..?

Comment: @tenepolis no it is as $x \to \infty$, ${1\over x} \to 0$. So you can't write ${1\over\infty} = 0$. If you write ${1\over\infty} = 0$, then even ${\infty \over \infty} = 1$, no point in doing the question :).

Comment: Understand, thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are assuming $a > 0$, but yes, it is correct.

Only weird thing is how you calculate the derivative of $x^a$; usually this is part of the "fundamental" derivatives that one learns, and should immediately be recognized as equal to $ax^{a-1}$. Your calculations yield the correct answer but it's a little weird ;-)

Comment: Ok thank you I don't know rule for derivating it that's why I change it with $e$ and $ln$ :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, even more is true. For $p>0$ and $q>0$, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log^px}{x^q}
 =\lim_{x\to\infty}\Bigl(\frac{\log x}{x^{q/p}}\Bigr)^p
 =\Bigl(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{q/p}}\Bigr)^p
 =\Bigl(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac1{(q/p)x^{q/p}}\Bigr)^p=0
$$
using continuity and l'Hôpital's rule.

Comment: Could anyone explain why my answer was downvoted?

Comment: I upvote so is neutralized :)
Not fair to down vote answer imo..

Comment: @tenepolis while downvotes for no reason are not fair, upvotes for the sake of neutralizing aren't fair either. IMO downvotes should be used when something is wrong with an answer, by the same logic upvotes should be used if the answer is a) correct and b) good in some ways (you like the reasoning, the technique. used..). Not pointing fingers at at anyone, but another answer here is wrong, therefor I downvoted and commented on that answer. Another person upvoted for whatever reason I don't understand.

Comment: Ok you right about that but it's not nice still. I mean, people might be wrong sometimes they do mistakes but he has tried to help me and put his time into writing an answer for me. Why punish him for doing that? Instead, it would be nicer in keeping the answer neutral and commenting it, the mistake. So everyone is aware it's wrong answer. As long as there is no personal insult in answer, I don't see why give minus credits.

Comment: @tenepolis I'm sorry to burst your bubble, but the world (of mathematics) is not about being nice. A downvote is not a statement against the writer but against the content of his answer. I don't mean to punish anyone but rather to point out mistakes. And not all people read comments, so downvotes are important to see directly if an answer is accepted by the community or if there are problems. The author is free to edit his answer and if he does so and corrects his mistake, I will remove my downvote. But this discussion has nothing to do with Cm7F7Bb (good) answer, so I'll stop discussing here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the simpler tool called Squeeze Theorem instead? If $a > 0$ then we choose $b$ such that $0 < b < a$ so that $a - b > 0$. Since $x \to \infty$ we can safely assume $x > 1$. And then $x^{b} > 1$ because $b > 0$. We have the inequality $$0 < \log x < x - 1$$ for all $x > 1$ and hence replacing $x$ by $x^{b}$ we get $$0 < b\log x < x^{b} - 1 < x^{b}$$ or $$0 < \log x < \frac{x^{b}}{b}$$ or $$0 < \frac{\log x}{x^{a}} < \frac{1}{bx^{a - b}}$$ By Squeeze theorem we now get $$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\log x}{x^{a}} = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

Because I'm not a fan of using L'Hospital whenever one has a limit of the Form $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, here is a way that makes use of the fact that $\ln$ is the inverse function of $\exp$:

We first show the following:

> Let $P:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a polynomial, then $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{P(x)}{\exp(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} P(x)\exp(x)$$ where $\exp:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R,~x\mapsto \sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}$.

Let $n$ be the degree of the polynomial $P$. We can find $c>0$ and $R>0$ with $$\left|P(x)\right|\leq c|x|^n~\text{for all}~x\geq R.$$ Further we have for $x\geq 0$:
$$\exp(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k!}\stackrel{x\geq 0}\geq\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$
and therefor we have
$$\left|\frac{P(x)}{\exp(x)}\right|\leq \frac{cx^n}{\frac{1}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}}=\frac{c\cdot(n+1)!}{x}$$
for all $x\geq R$. Using the squeeze theorem we now get:
$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{P(x)}{\exp(x)}=0~\text{and}~\lim\limits_{x\to -\infty} P(x)\exp(x)=\lim\limits_{w\to\infty} \frac{P(-w)}{\exp(w)}=0.$$

We will use this to prove the following:

> Let $\alpha\in\mathbb R_+^*$. Then $$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{\ln(x)}{x^{\alpha}}=0.$$

Let $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be a sequence in $\mathbb R_+^*$ with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} x_n=\infty$. We then also have for $y_n:=\alpha\ln(x_n)$ that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} y_n=\infty$.

As $$x_n^{\alpha}=\exp(y_n)$$ we now get:
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(x_n)}{x_n^{\alpha}}=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha}y_n\exp(-y_n)=0.$$